Concatenating Strings in Power Query (M) by Delimiters Position
I currently have two columns of strings like the following. And want to concatenate the two columns together to make the third using Power Query. I have been trying to find a way for several days with no luck. If a way could be found using DAX I would accept that solution as well.

I have tried several different "list.*" type functions, and tried to use different text functions with no avail.

In powerquery, Add column ... custom column ... with
= Text.Combine(let a=Text.Split([Measurements Taken],","), b=Text.Split([#"# of Measurment"],",") in List.Transform(List.Positions (a), each a{_}&"-"&b{_}),",")

or
= Text.Combine(List.Transform(List.Zip({Text.Split([Measurements Taken],","),Text.Split([#"# of Measurment"],",")}), each _{0}&"-"&_{1}),",")



Do you really need the second column?
If you do not, you can create your Desired Column directly from just the first column:
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Measurements Taken", type text}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Desired Column", each 
        let 
            nums=List.Transform(Text.Split([Measurements Taken],","),each Text.From(_)),
            pos = List.Transform(List.Numbers(1,List.Count(nums)),each Text.From(_)),
            zip = List.Zip({nums,pos}),
            combine = List.Transform(zip, each Text.Combine(_,"-"))
        in 
            Text.Combine(combine,", "), type text)
in
    #"Added Custom"


